# Getting this error when trying to setup bench on my Mac with OS Catalina: ERROR: No matching distribution found for RestrictedPython~=6.0

Tags: macos, terminal, mysql-workbench, erpnext, frappe

I get this error when trying to setup `bench`:

```
**(base) sarthakkatiyar@sanjay-mishra-3 ~ % cd ~                     
bench init frappe-bench**
Setting Up Environment
$ python3 -m venv env
$ /Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade pip
$ /Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet wheel
Getting frappe
$ git clone https://github.com/frappe/frappe.git  --depth 1 --origin upstream
Cloning into 'frappe'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3213, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3213/3213), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2848/2848), done.
remote: Total 3213 (delta 402), reused 1989 (delta 267), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3213/3213), 17.15 MiB | 4.14 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (402/402), done.
Installing frappe
$ /Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/apps/frappe 
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 5.1 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <3.10; 5.2 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <3.11; 5.2a1.dev0 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <3.11; 5.3a1.dev0 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <3.12; 6.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.12; 6.0a1.dev0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.12
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement RestrictedPython~=6.0 (from frappe) (from versions: 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.6.0a1, 3.6.0, 4.0a1, 4.0a2, 4.0a3, 4.0b1, 4.0b2, 4.0b3, 4.0b4, 4.0b5, 4.0b6, 4.0b7, 4.0b8, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0a1.dev0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for RestrictedPython~=6.0
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /Users/sarthakkatiyar/frappe-bench/apps/frappe ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/commands/make.py", line 68, in init
    init(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 105, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/utils/system.py", line 79, in init
    get_app(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/app.py", line 444, in get_app
    app.install(verbose=verbose, skip_assets=skip_assets, restart_bench=restart_bench)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 126, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/app.py", line 242, in install
    install_app(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/app.py", line 573, in install_app
    bench.run(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/bench.py", line 48, in run
    return exec_cmd(cmd, cwd=cwd or self.cwd, _raise=_raise)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bench/utils/__init__.py", line 158, in exec_cmd
    raise CommandFailedError from subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)
bench.exceptions.CommandFailedError
**
ERROR: There was a problem while creating frappe-bench**
Do you want to rollback these changes? [y/N]: y
INFO: Rolling back Bench "frappe-bench"
(base) sarthakkatiyar@sanjay-mishra-3 ~ % python --version
Python 3.12.0b1
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement RestrictedPython~=6.0 (from frappe) (from versions: 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.6.0a1, 3.6.0, 4.0a1, 4.0a2, 4.0a3, 4.0b1, 4.0b2, 4.0b3, 4.0b4, 4.0b5, 4.0b6, 4.0b7, 4.0b8, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0a1.dev0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for RestrictedPython~=6.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to install Frappe develop `([pre-]version-15)` with Python 3.9 (Your tracebacks show this). However, Frappe develop has a minimum requirement of Python 3.10 as defined [here](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/774a75dbdeea16cd14eb215bbe4e7b1c0213b465/pyproject.toml#LL7C1-L7C27) in its build file.

When I want to setup a Bench for v13 Frappe that needs Python3.7, I run the following command:

```bash
bench init v13-bench-2023 --version version-13 --python $(which python3.7)
```

If you have `3.10` installed on your machine, find its installed path - typically by `$(which python3.10)`, and pass it along with the bench init command.